# recursively copy files(with same name) to one folder

Tags: shell, unix

I have a bunch of files in separate folders, that have the same name.

For example,

```
/path/to/your/directory/1/results.pdf
/path/to/your/directory/2/results.pdf
```

But, I would like to copy them to the one directory:

```
/path/to/your/directory/results/
```

so I have:

```
/path/to/your/directory/results/results-1.pdf 
/path/to/your/directory/results/results-2.pdf
```

etc

The trouble being that the scripts I write, the files will overwrite each other.

Thanks

Comment: So, what do you want the script to do instead?

Comment: Implement a simple counter that adds a numeric postfix to each files basename. So you end up with results-001.pdf, results-002.pdf, ... Waht is the problem here?

Comment: How does the script look like? Usually you can check if the file exists on the target and if yes you rename it (append a number etc).

Comment: I just had a simple find code.

for file in $(find ./ -name "*.pdf")
do
cp $file /path/to/your/directory
done

Comment: Check this: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/05/copy-multiple-files-with-same-name-in.html

Answer (score 1):

I do this regularly

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

for i in `find <source_dir_path> -type f`
do
new=`echo $i|nawk -F"/" '{split($NF,a,".");print "<target_dir_path>"a[1]"_"$(NF-1)"."a[2]}'`
cp $i $new
done
```

Comment: A few levels deep within each subfolder of a directory, I have the files spm_2013Jun05.ps.I have been trying to move the files into /home/alistair/Documents/spmresults/. But only two itterations of the same filename have actually copied:
-/home/alistair/Documents/spmresults/spm_2013Jun05.ps
-/home/alistair/Documents/spmresults/spm_2013Jun05_1.ps

    for i in $(find ./ -name spm_2013May30.ps -type f)
    do
    new=`echo $i|nawk -F"/" '{split($NF,a,".");                  print"/home/alistair/Documents/spmresults/"a[1]"_"$(NF-1)"."a[2]}'`
    cp $i $new
    done

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this will help you
`find . -type f -exec sh -c 'if [ ! -e ../aaa/{} ]; then cp {} ../aaa/;else i=0; while [ -e ../aaa/{}_${i} ]; do ((i++)); done; cp {} ../aaa/{}_${i}; fi' \;`

So basically it searches from a current dir, and for any file, it will copy to `../aaa/` dir, if there is already any such file exists, it will append `_0` or `_1` or ... whichever makes it uniq, ideally it should be written in a script and `find -exec` should call for the script if any further refinement is needed, but i think this one liner should be enough

Answer (score 0):

To [rename the files in place](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/4f661e86f5a930f3508e36dc53a7cc147584cc6d/.bash_history#L1348) as `result-0001.pdf`, `result-0002.pdf` etc., so you can move them without any problems:

```
rename --no-act --verbose 's/.*/sprintf "result-%04d.pdf", ++$main::Mad/e' /path/to/your/directory/results/*/result.pdf
```

Remove `--no-act` if you're happy with the result.